# Including Vue.js into Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have seen some tutorial on how to include Vue.js into Laravel projects.
As far as I can see the tutorials are using Vue.js by creating templates and importing them into the blade-files. Is there anything "wrong" in just including the Vue javascript file directly into blade-files and using Vue directly like that? In other words just using:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

in the blade-files I want to use Vue.

The reason for this is that I just want Vue.js to replace some of the work that has been done by Jquery in the application. I have also been thinking about using React. But it seems like that goes the same way as Vue (creating templates, which then should be imported into the corresponding blade-files).

I use Laravel 5.6.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Why not use [Laravel 5 Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix). Which by default already has vue.js included out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great, I will try to explain my approach of doing such kind of replacement work.
Laravel comes with `assets` directory containing `js` and `css` directory. If you explore more the `js` directory you'd see two files `bootstrap.js` and `app.js`.
`bootstrap.js` file is nothing but few handy stuffs like setting `jQuery` as global object so that it can be accessed in vue instance easily, setting `axios` default header to have `X-CSRF-TOKEN` while using axios in the project.

But the important part is `app.js`. It initialises the vue instance and binds it with a `#app` div which mostly the first div after `<body>` tag.

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

In the above file, you can see there vue instance is created and it is bound to a div whose id is `app`. Along with that `Vue` is also registering a component called `example` which is stored under `js/components/` directory as [Example.vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Now, based on your requirement you can go ahead and follow these steps to create  components to replace some of jQuery codes without having any conflicts.

• Make sure to bind the the vue instance to root div so that you can use the component in the blade file this way.

```
<div id="something">
    <example></example>
</div>
```

• If you Laravel mix, make sure you compile the `app.js`

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

I have worked on projects have similar required modifications, I followed the way I just mentioned and worked quite well for me.
Feel free to ask any question you have. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but you will have to `new Vue` in every blade file then since you have a classic page reload when you switch from one blade file to the next (if they're not included in each other). I imagine that this is going to give you a lot of trouble sharing data between your various vue instances.